# How we can achieve to get the output inline in editor by using "//?"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio, vscode-extensions

I need extension name to get output by using '**//?**'

[image]

Comment: There is quokka which looks similar, not sure if it's the exact one being used in the screenshot though: https://quokkajs.com/docs/index.html

Comment: Thank you @NickParsons . quokka  is the one we are looking for. Thank you once again

Comment: @NickParsons you should consider writing your comment as an answer, so that it can be accepted (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment).

Comment: @Stanislas I would usually, but this question is about seeking recommendations for tools/software, which is an off-topic question for SO and should probably be closed as "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" (for that there is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)